# Loading images from folder in tableView slow

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have loaded images from folder in tableView with custom cell which has three images in each row.Even though i resized image it it slow when scroll up or down

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = customCell;
}

if ([imageLists count] > indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow) {

    ImagesClass *Obj1 = [imageLists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow];

    UIImage *image1 = [self getImageForImageId:Obj1.imageId FromPath:SAVEDIMAGE_DIR];
    Obj1.thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:image1 convertToSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)];

    [cell setImage:1 :Obj1.thumbImage RowNo:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow];
```

Comment: when i scroll down or up it is taking time to move up or down

Comment: put ur cellforrowatindexpath method

Comment: @guru what did u edit?

Comment: @user2003416, now see code, marked your code with 'code sample' block in stack overflow

Comment: @ipatel i added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lazy loading in your table view

```
   [cell setImage:2 :Obj2.thumbImage RowNo:indexPath.row*noOfImageInRow+1];
```

These functions take more time to execute

```
UIImage *image1 = [self getImageForImageId:Obj1.imageId FromPath:SAVEDIMAGE_DIR];
Obj1.thumbImage = [self imageWithImage:image1 convertToSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)];
```

Refer Apple for Lazy Loading image Concepts.

I wont describe what is lazy loading, hope this much works for you

Comment: @CreazyCreator I have referred it.little bit confusion on changing my code.Can u give some outline?